# Problemas ao desenhar um oval em um painel (JAVA)

Tags: java

Saudações caros amigos programadores.

Estou me deparando com um erro um tanto irritante:
Cogito desenhar um grafo na tela utilizando formas circulares/ovais. Após um bom número de pesquisas, me sugeriram utilizar uma classe que extendesse JPanel/JComponent ***(testei com ambas)***, e utilizasse um metodo de pintura usando Graphics, que fosse chamado por paintComponent.

Fiz isso de várias maneiras, e no fim do dia, a mesma coisa persiste: Quadradinhos pintados de branco.

[image]

Está sendo desenhado dessa maneira atualmente. Gostaria que os painéis se tornassem círculos.

[image]

Este é o código que uso para fazer tal coisa. Descrevi nos comentários para facilitar a visualização.

---

Aqui está  classe que criei baseada nos 300 exemplos que existem de drawOval em java.

```
public class Bolinha extends JPanel{


public void pintar(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillOval(50, 50, 20, 20);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    pintar(g);
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Infelizmente não posso postar mais imagens, mas utilizando este código:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < g.getListaDeVertices().size(); i++){
        v1 = g.getListaDeVertices().get(i); //Pega o vértice
        Bolinha bola = new Bolinha();
        bola.setSize(30, 30);
        bola.setLocation(v1.getPosX(), v1.getPosY() + 180);
        bola.setVisible(true);
        bola.setBackground(Color.white);
        bola.add(new Label(Integer.toString(g.getListaDeVertices().get(i).getIdMatriz())));
        PainelDesenho.add(bola);
        listaDePaineis.add(p);
```

acabo obtendo o mesmo resultado (quadradinhos) em vez de ***bolinhas.***

Sinto muito pela falta das outras imagens. Agradeço a quem puder ajudar!
Um grande abraço,
Momentanius.

Comment: Um palpite: na sobreescrita do método _paintComponent_, chame _super.paintComponent(g)_ e, só depois, _pintar(g)_.

Comment: Um amigo meu informou a mesma coisa, e nothing. Muito esquisito. Agradeço a ajuda, ainda assim!

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu percebi, o erro está em cada nó do grafo ser um novo **JPanel**. A função **bola.setBackground(Color.white);** está definindo o background do seu **JPanel** para branco e, por isso, que fica um quadrado branco.

Uma solução que eu posso sugerir, é criar uma classe chamada Grafo que extenda um **JPanel**. Essa classe vai receber como parâmetro no seu construtor a lista de vértices e desenhar os respectivos nós. Ou seja, você terá apenas um **JPanel** que irá desenhar todos os nós do grafos no seu **JFrame**, entendeu? Um exemplo, só para ter uma ideia, de como seria:

```
  class Grafo extends JPanel {

  Lista listaDeVertices

  Grafo(Lista listaDeVertices) {

    this.listaDeVertices = listaDeVertices;

    setFocusable(true);
    setDoubleBuffered(true);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    repaint();
    setVisible(true);

  }

  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);
    update(g);

  }

  @Override
  public void update(Graphics g) {

    for(int i = 0; i < listaDeVertices.size(); i++) {

      v1 = listaDeVertices.get(i);
      g.drawOval(v1.getPosX(), v1.getPosY()+180, 30, 30);

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Eu queria que isso fosse um comentário, mas não tenho reputação suficiente. Fica como uma resposta bem média, mas tudo bem.